# Are there any hard SAT instances that can be quickly solved?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, satisfiability

Are there any hard SAT instances that can be quickly solved?

Is there a special case?

I'm not talking about the whole SAT.

But are there any special cases of hard SAT formulas that can be solved in polynomial time?

We exclude class P resulting from [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem) for the SAT.

--- Edit:

I may have asked the wrong question:

Are there such special cases known? - "known" - it should be.

Comment: See [cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). And if you know [Schaefer'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem) theorem then you should be able to make your question much more precise ?

Comment: I don't understand what it would mean for an instance to be "hard" if it could be quickly solved. Wouldn't the existence of  a quick solution demonstrate that the instance wasn't hard?